# How do I obtain the address of a function?

Tags: rust

How do I obtain a function address in Rust? What does '&somefunction' exactly mean?

What addresses do I get doing

```
std::mem::transmute::<_, u32>(function)
```

or

```
std::mem::transmute::<_, u32>(&function)
```

(on 32-bit system, of course)?

What does

```
&function as *const _ as *const c_void
```

give?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)? It would allow you to answer questions like "what output does this code have" yourself.

Comment: If you wish to store a pointer in an integral, use `usize` instead of either `u32` or `u64`, it's guaranteed to have the same size as a pointer.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I know what is the output of this code (I kbow how to run rust programs, yeah ;-) ), the question is about what exact addresses do i get and you answer below sheds light on it.

Comment: @ Matthieu M.: thanks, I know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I just wanted to know the address of a function, I'd probably just print it out:

```
fn moo() {}

fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", moo as *const ());
}
```

However, I can't think of a useful reason to want to do this. Usually, there's something you want to *do* with the function. In those cases, you might as well just pass the function directly, no need to deal with the address:

```
fn moo() {}

fn do_moo(f: fn()) {
    f()
}

fn main() {
    do_moo(moo);
}
```

I'm less sure about this, but I think that `std::mem::transmute::<_, u32>(&function)` would just create a local variable that points to `function` and then gets the reference to that variable. This would match how this code works:

```
fn main() {
    let a = &42;
}
```

> I need not to work with them in Rust, I need an address because I have some FFI that takes an address of the symbol in the current process

You can still just pass the function as-is to the extern functions that will use the callback:

```
extern {
    fn a_thing_that_does_a_callback(callback: extern fn(u8) -> bool);
}

extern fn zero(a: u8) -> bool { a == 0 }

fn main() {
    unsafe { a_thing_that_does_a_callback(zero); }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are right about what the reference does, thanks. I know how to work with functions. But I need not to work with them in Rust, I need an address because I have some FFI that takes an address of the symbol in the current process (yes, my function is marked as extern, so it has the right call conventions).

Comment: > You can still just pass the function as-is to the extern functions that will use the callback. No, I can't. Extern function accepts addresses. Period. But your comments (with println!) helped, thanks. I have used it in these commits: https://github.com/jauhien/iron-kaleidoscope/commit/154136f732f685eb6ab206e26c1f79a91de2f8b2 and https://github.com/jauhien/iron-llvm/commit/eae180417912eeade7c35b16a12bdce69ebfaf84

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Shepmaster gives answer to this question (though giving also other not relevant but may be useful for somebody information). I summarize it here.

Obtaining address is easy, just

```
funct as *const ()
```

Reference to a function seems to create a local variable just like with

```
let a = &42;
```